# Cannot represent relocation type BFD_RELOC_X86_64_GOTPC64

Tags: assembly, linker, mingw, x86-64, relocation

I get this error whenever I try to use `-mcmodel=large` does anyone know why this is?

I am on Windows 10 using gcc 10.2.0

Comment: I didn't think Windows dynamic linking used a GOT (Global Offset Table) by that name; are you sure you're actually building native Windows executables, rather than WSL or a cross-compiler?  Or maybe that's the problem, if GAS / `ld` don't support `-mcmodel=large` for Windows `.obj` files?   I can build a tiny C program on my Linux machine with that option, but it doesn't use any global variables so I don't think the code-gen is even different.

Comment: I am using the msys-gcc compiler on Windows. Would that be what you are talking about when you say cross compiling?

Comment: A cross-compiler would be something like `x86_64-elf-gcc` to run on Windows but build Linux executables (which use a GOT).  If you're using MinGW on Msys, you're not doing that.  I'd guess that `-mcmodel=large` might not be supported for Windows targets, and the failure mode might be to make asm that does it the Linux way, resulting in failure to assemble or link, you didn't give details on which step gave that error.

Answer (score 0):

I *think* this was because I was passing it as a compiler flag instead of a linker flag.

Comment: For it to work correctly, `-mcmodel=large` needs to be used as you compile, to get the compiler to emit different instructions / instruction-sequences for calling functions that might be more than +-2GiB away, as well as for referencing static data with 64-bit absolute addressing, not RIP-relative.  The linker can't change that; the necessary instructions are larger (which is one reason this isn't the default) so the linker can't rewrite existing machine code to have room for it.  Passing `-mcmodel=large` is probably the same as not using it at all, and avoids 64-bit absolute codegen.

Comment: Weird then because when I passed it as a compiler option I kept getting the same error but when I passed as a linker option it just worked. I wonder if bazel does something weird with linker options then.

Comment: Seems like whatever you're building doesn't actually need it, at least on Windows.  Do you really have more than a 2GiB `.text` section (machine code)?  It's very rare to need the performance hit of `large`, usually just `-mcmodel=medium` is sufficient if you have a few huge static arrays.  (Or more normally, the default code model is totally fine, with .text+.data+.bss size being under 2GiB; most programs use dynamic allocation for huge arrays).  And are you claiming you get some kind of link error if you omit any `-mcmodel=` options from the linking stage?

Comment: Oh yeah `-mcmodel=medium` worked just fine too! Good to know. Yes the error I get happens during linking. It is very weird.

Comment: You mean there's a different error if you don't use `-mcmodel=` during compiling or linking, like something about a relocation truncated to fit, or out of range, and it happens during linking?  If no, then why do you think you need a `-mcmodel` option at all?

Comment: The error of this post is the error I get whether I set `-mcmodel` as a compiler option or not at all. When I set it as a linker option I get no error and the build succeeds.

Comment: Right, so what if you don't specify `-mcmodel` anywhere, either for compile or link?  If that also works, that would support my argument that providing it as a linker option is probably doing nothing, and that your program doesn't need it.

Comment: If I don't specify it anywhere I get the above error. I don't know why it works!